# Using Alamofire and Objectmapper the integer value always zero for double value

Tags: swift, alamofire, objectmapper

return object of `map["balance"]` is

```
"responseMap": {
    "balance": 9689.5
}
```

But when I transform as follow, return value gone to `0`.

```
balance <- (map["balance"],TransformOf<String,Int>(fromJSON: { String(NSNumber(value: $0 ?? 0).intValue) }, toJSON: { $0.map({ Int($0) ?? 0 }) }))
```

Please let me know how to fix return value to `9689.5` instead of `0`

Comment: maybe `map["responseMap"]["balance"]` ?

Comment: @Sandu nope, above code transform to `0` if balance is double/float.

Comment: do you need this transform-stuff ? I'm using objectmapper too, but for me `id <- map["id"]` is working as well